# play and record with 20khz

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i want to play and record an audio at the same time but it doesnt work i was making a 20khz and its ok and i was testing that in 10khz but when i play it 20 khz or 10 khz , it doesnt record i dont know how to record it but when i was talking in front of my laptop ,it will be recorded
at the end i was plot that on a spectrugram and i was truly see that.
i dont know what should i do
i was tried on this code and this is my code

```py
import numpy as np
import pyaudio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import sounddevice as sd
import librosa
import librosa.display
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import os
from scipy import signal
import soundfile as sf
import IPython.display as ipd
import threading
import wave
SAMPLE_RATE = 44100  
FREQUENCY = 10000  
DURATION = 5  
AMPLITUDE = 0.5  

def play_record_stereo(chirp_signal, SAMPLE_RATE):
    recording=sd.playrec(chirp_signal,samplerate=SAMPLE_RATE,channels=1)
    sd.wait()
    return recording[:, 0]

t=np.linspace(0,DURATION,SAMPLE_RATE*DURATION, False)
audio_signal=AMPLITUDE*np.sin(FREQUENCY*2*np.pi*t)
recording1=play_record_stereo(audio_signal,SAMPLE_RATE)
x=recording1
print(type(x),type(SAMPLE_RATE))
print(x.shape,SAMPLE_RATE)
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))
librosa.display.waveshow(x,sr=SAMPLE_RATE)
X=librosa.stft(x)
Xdb=librosa.amplitude_to_db(abs(X))
plt.figure(figsize=(14,5))
librosa.display.specshow(Xdb,sr=SAMPLE_RATE,x_axis='time',y_axis='hz')
plt.colorbar()
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
librosa.display.specshow(Xdb, sr=SAMPLE_RATE, x_axis='time', y_axis='log')
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: What happens when "it doesn't record"? Is there an error message? If so, what?